# Are there any conditions on the moments that make a measure a probability measure?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, moments

For a positive Borel measure $\mu$ on the  <s>real line</s>  interval $[-1, 1]$, let $\displaystyle{m_n = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^n d\mu(x)}$, i.e. the $n$th moments of the measure.  Are there any conditions on $m_n$, $n \ge 1$, for when $\mu$ can be made into a probability measure, i.e. $\mu(\mathbb{R}) < \infty$?  Recall that the moments of a uniform distribution on $[-1,1]$ are $1/(n+1)$ for even $n$.  The measure given by density $p(x)= 1/(2|x|)$ for $x \in [-1,1]$ has moments $1/n$ for even $n$.  So it seems that two moment sequences with very similar asymptotic behavior can give different answers to this question.

**Edit:**
Actually, consider the additional example of the densities $1/(4\sqrt{x})$ and $1/4(1/x-1/\sqrt{x})$ in $[-1,1]$ which have even moments $1/(2n+1)$ and $1/(2n(2n+1))$ respectively.  So some sort of upper bound condition on the moments is certainly out of the question.  In fact, are there two measures $\mu$ with and $\nu$ that both have the moment sequence $m_1,m_2,...$ where one is finite and the other is infinite?

Comment: Since there is a nonzero function on the real line with all moments zero, the answer is most likely no

Comment: This seems to be a special case of the Markov Moment Problem, where you include the zeroth moment $m_0$ to ensure that the total measure is $1$. Is this what you are looking for? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem

Comment: Ah, since you also have that the density is positive, the answer may be yes...

Comment: @AlonAmit, I don't think that wikipedia article references the Markov problem (I found a statement anyhow).  Yes, I think the Markov Moment Problem gives a partial answer.  It seems to be restricted to measures of bounded support though.

Comment: @maridia no, the moment problem covers the unbounded support case as well. It is sometimes called more specifically the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_moment_problem.

Comment: I see, yes.  I suppose that technically answers my question since the condition then is just whether there exists a finite $m_0$ that meets the Hamburger condition.  I guess my situation is slightly different in that I already know that the moments come from some measure.  I was hoping for a simpler condition to just check finiteness of $m_0$.